# residential areas for expat in Leiden

Tags: netherlands, accommodation

What are the areas that expat live in, in Leiden

Using wikipedia, I found that Leiden has the following suburbs

Oegstgeest, Leiderdorp, Voorschoten and Zoeterwoude

My employer office is located at Jupiterlaan

Any information about Leiden accommodation is appreciated

Comment: I've lived in Leiden for 20 years, but have never noticed specific areas. Since Leiden is a university city (that has its spinoff into industry), there are a lot of foreigners, both students and expats. My guess is most live in Leiden itself. The city is not so large that travelling from a quarter to the city center will take much time (get a bike).